# Nginx redirect loop when using HTTP basic authentication

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I'm trying to setup basic authentication for all of my site, but I'm getting a redirect loop when I try to enable it. Current config works, but when I add

```
auth_basic           "Secured";
auth_basic_user_file /var/www/*****/.htpasswd;
```

under     location / {

it redirects endlessly to mysite.com/login and fails. mysite.com/login is the login page for the script I'm using, but it is not supposed to redirect there upon visiting the homepagepage and it does not do so normally. I am not sure if something in my script is causing the redirect loop, or my nginx config but I would like to figure a way to enable basic HTTP authentication.

Any ideas would be most appreciated, thank you.

```
server {
    server_name  ***** www.*****;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /var/www/******/public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        include fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        internal;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/*****/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/*****/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.*****) {
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = *****) {
        return 302 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen   80;
    server_name  ***** www.*****;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: Do you also have security set up in Symfony? If so, could you post your `security.yml`, especially the firewalls and access controls-sections?

Comment: Have you tried placing the `auth_basic` statements in the `server` block instead of the `location /` block?

Comment: @RichardSmith yes, I tried placing them in the server block but the result was the same.

Comment: @dbrumann No, I haven't set up security myself. I did search for security.yml in the application folder, but didn't find anything